# Angular JS, Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'myCtrl1' is not registered

Tags: angularjs

This is my sample angular code, when i try to run it it says

```
Module 'myApp1' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

My code:

```
    <script>
(function() {
angular.module('myApp1',[]).controller('myCtrl1', [ '$scope', '$timeout',
        function( $scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.firstName = "divya";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
}]);
})();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="ProjectView" ng-app='myApp1' ng-controller="myCtrl1">
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div
```

>

Comment: put your script after the angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

There are following mistakes in your code:

1. You don't have dependency array in `angular.module` statement. What you have in your code is the module getter, and doesn't initialize a module. Hence AngularJS throws the error that you mentioned.
2. You don't have `ng-app="myApp1"` in your HTML. You may have omitted this in this example, but I'm taking into account this one as well.

Correcting these, your code works fine. See the example below:

```js
angular.module('myApp1', []).controller('myCtrl1', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.firstName = "divya";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp1" id="ProjectView" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br> Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
  <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
```

Comment: I update the code as suggested, am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**The order of scripts matter**. First you need to load `angular.js` library, and then add your script. Otherwise it will complain that `angular` is not defined (in `anuglar.module()`)

So try swapping the order of scripts like this. First is HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="ProjectView" ng-app='myApp1' ng-controller="myCtrl1">
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
  <br>
  Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
```

**Then** your JavaScript:

```
<script>
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp1',[]).
  controller('myCtrl1', [ '$scope', '$timeout', function( $scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.firstName = "divya";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  }]);
})();
</script>
```